# Py2exe для Python 3.3.3

Tags: python, компилятор

Всем доброго дня.

Хотел бы узнать существует ли какая нибудь программа, аналог py2exe для python 3.3.3
Насколько мне известно py2exe поддерживает только python 2.7

Заранее спасибо

Comment: [cx-freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) пробовали? Но смысла никакого в преобразовании в exe не вижу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант cx_Freeze http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/ качать напрямую с https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=cx_Freeze&version=4.3.3

Answer (score 0):

а вот он [тут](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe). 
под 3.6 работает